# Good tutorials on refactoring Javascript into a JavaScript MVC frameworks?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, refactoring

I'm looking for tutorial(s) on how to refactor JavaScript application into a JavaScript application using one of the existing JS MVC frameworks. Anyone got any?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I recommend the Backbone-Boilerplate located at [GitHub](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate).

This is beneficial because, not only do you get the Backbone MVC, but also require.js AMD, and underscore.js templates. The authors have been consistently active, and the code is impressive to work with.

Here are the associated tutorials:

1. [Introduction](http://weblog.bocoup.com/introducing-the-backbone-boilerplate/)
2. [AMD Module setup](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/)
3. [Boilerplate](http://backboneboilerplate.com/)
4. [Overview](http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/05/17/getting-familiar-with-backbone-boilerplate/)
5. [Router Explanation](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/)

These were the tutorials I used to get it up and running. Also included is Node.js and Grunt build system. They are very much worth the effort if you are not familiar with them. I just saw today that a jQuery project is incorporating the Grunt build system. This is a good setup.

UPDATE: Apologies if you were already aware of the boilerplate. I realize it does not directly relate to refactoring. This looks like a good post on refactoring [MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685282/refactor-to-use-oop-mvc).

Documentation may be sparse as it would be specific to how your codebase is architected. The key notion would be Data maps to Model, GUI maps to View, Collections contain multiple models, and the Router is used to route events.

Hope that helps.
All the best!
Nash

Comment: is everything javascript? Since you're talking about node.js I guess so, but could you confirm?

Comment: Yes, everything is JavaScript. In addition the Node.js and Grunt includes are straightforward to configure. I was initially apprehensive, but was very glad to have followed the instructions all the way through. Both are an excellent introduction into advancing technologies. The grunt build system is also much nicer than ant, and worth keeping an eye on. It is a JavaScript based build tool.

Comment: wow, so, good bye php? Is the framework robust enough you think? to support as many various operations that could allow php existing modules?

Comment: Good point for clarification, Node.js is not required as a server. It is simply utilized for installation of the build system , which also isn't required(via NPM). The front-end MVC can be pushed to any server you choose, and can be built (minified, concat, linted) with any methodology you choose (ant). I found it robust but have not stress-tested it. All the best! Nash